# NSPredicate Crashes when trying to use CONTAINS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

The data structure that I want to question. `Data` is a `Transformable` field which in turn is a `NSDictionary`.

```
Obj = { //...
    NSDictionary *data:@{
                         likesPeople:@[@{@"username":@"jack",@"id":@"ae3132"}]
                         }
}
```

what I want to do is search inside the `NSArray *fetchResult` to check that there is noone in `likesPeople` with X `id` .
 My attempts on doing this always end up crashing highlighting that there is a problem in my `NSPredicate` declaration.

What am I doing wrong and How could I effectively fetch the information that I want?

```
SocialWall *theSocialWall = fetchResult[0];
        NSLog(@"%@",theSocialWall.data);
        NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"data.likesPeople CONTAINS(c) %@",myUser.userWebID];

        NSArray * result = [fetchResult filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not Contains(c) but Contains[c]

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSDictionary *d = @{@"key":@"hi my name dominik pich"};
    NSArray *a = @[d];
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key CONTAINS[c] %@",@"dominik"];
    NSArray * result = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
}
```